# How to get and set OID value in custom SNMP MIB

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I am very new to SNMP and I need to get "system uptime" using our own enterprise OID.

I have already obtained an `IANA number` and created a MIB file.

The problem is when I use `snmpget` command with our OID, I get an `object not found` error at the command prompt.

Although when I do a `snmptranslate` on our object, I get the exact OID of that object.

If any additional information is required from my side, please let me know.

Comment: I have the same issue, is it resolved ?

Comment: How to run snmpset command when we make a custom oid using net-snmp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `snmpget`, an SNMP request is made via IP to an SNMP agent on a remote (or local) host to return a specific piece of data. A MIB is used to describe in human readable terms, what that data is and where to find it. On the other hand, `snmptranslate` is a tool used to parse a given MIB. It parses a local MIB file, and doesn't make any contact with an agent.

Since you mentioned creating a new MIB, I assume your trying to add new functionality to an SNMP agent. To do this, the agent must be extended. If you're using Net-SNMP, there are a few options including compiling new source code into the agent, using a sub-agent, and using external scripts via pass and pass-persist protocol. Take a look at:

- http://www.net-snmp.org
- http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2012-extending-netsnmp.html

Comment: I am using this (http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Writing_a_MIB_Module) link to Compile  my new MIB module.Example given in this link is working Correct . But when I am using snmpget  for my enterprise  custom OID , it is giving  error ( " No Such Object available on this agent at this OID").

Comment: Can you post the snmpget command, contents and location of snmpd.conf. Be sure your ending your snmpget command with a .0 and you have a v2 community or v3 user defined in your snmpd.conf files. You might also want to try an snmpwalk command on your enterprise tree.

Comment: Location of snmpd.conf is '/usr/local/etc/snmpd.conf'. Contents of snmpd.conf is "rwcommunity public" .